# How can I make a Layout's Canvas move together with the Layout?

Tags: python, colors, background, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and Python in general and have visited this page many, many times. This time, however, I can't seem to find a good solution, or rather any solution, online. So, I figured I'd make my first post. If someone can help me figure this one out it would be greatly appreciated.

**THE PROBLEM**

For a one-look understanding of my problem, please see screenshots below. I am working on a GUI which shows a bunch of Items in a StackLayout. These items are Layouts themselves and also have a background color. When I first add these widgets, everything is working absolutely fine. When I remove them, though, the Layouts stack rightly back together, but they leave their canvases behind.

This seems like such a trivial problem that I thought there must be a one-liner fix. But as I said, I really couldn't find anything useful. Now, I kind of understand why that happens. My approaches would be to somehow link the Canvas' positioning dynamically to the widget's position, but I don't know how to go about that. What I also tried was erasing the canvas of the parent widget to redraw the backgrounds whenever I remove a line. But `canvas.before.clear()` does nothing and `canvas.clear()` empties everything and not just the background color.

**CODE**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<TopLayout>:
    Button:
        text: 'Remove middle line'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        on_press: root.remove_middle_line()
<Line>:
    size_hint: 1, .1
    Label:
        text: 'This is a line with a background-color'
""")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TopLayout()

class TopLayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global middle_line
        middle_line = Line()
        self.add_widget(Line())
        self.add_widget(middle_line)
        self.add_widget(Line())

    def remove_middle_line(self):
        self.remove_widget(middle_line)


class Line(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)

    def init_ui(self, delta=0):
        if self.pos == [0, 0]:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)
        else:
            with self.canvas.before:
                Color(.4, .2, .2, .8)
                Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

TestApp().run()
```

**EXAMPLE**

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85VvA.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYiPf.png)

Cheers and thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

Funnily, I figured it out right after publishing this post. I added a redraw method for which I created a list of all the lines. It redraws all background colors on line removal.

```
lines = []

...

    def remove_middle_line(self):
        self.remove_widget(middle_line)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.redraw, 0)

    def redraw(self, delta=0):
        for line in lines:
            line.canvas.before.clear()
            with line.canvas.before:
                Color(.4, .2, .2, .8)
                Rectangle(size=line.size, pos=line.pos)

...

class Line(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)
        lines.append(self)
```

[Now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjURg.png)

But since this seems like a work-around, I would still like to leave this question open. Maybe someone has a suggestion of how to make those two move together instead of having to redraw all of the backgrounds every time I move lines. Thanks again, <3

Comment: Note that clearing and redrawing everything is extremely inefficient, instead you should maintain references to the objects you create the first time then update their properties (i.e. size and pos for Rectangle).

Comment: Also the reason your kv solution works is that it does essentially what you have here, except that it automatically creates the bindings you need (and as above it updates the instructions instead of recreating them). The ease of doing this is one of the points of kv.

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a blog that I'm doing than a question haha. I figured it out. It's not so difficult actually. This just shows me how valuable it is to reduce a problem to its core code. When there's hundreds of other lines it's considerably harder to see what's wrong. The solution for this case for me was to simply define the canvas in the Kivy-Code itself. Why I didn't want to do that in the first place was because of a boolean-based check that I am doing, resulting in different background colors. But I can overcome this by assigning a ListProperty and just changing it at initialization. So here is the simple solution, including the ListProperty.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<TopLayout>:
    Button:
        text: 'Remove middle line'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        on_press: root.remove_middle_line()
<Line>:
    size_hint: 1, .1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bgcol
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text: 'This is a line with a background-color'
""")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TopLayout()

class TopLayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global middle_line
        middle_line = Line()
        self.add_widget(Line())
        self.add_widget(middle_line)
        self.add_widget(Line())

    def remove_middle_line(self):
        self.remove_widget(middle_line)

class Line(StackLayout):
    bgcol = ListProperty([.4, .2, .2, .8])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # if something: self.bgcol = [.2, .5, .2, .8]

TestApp().run()
```

I will leave this alternative solution for anyone who might be interested:

Instead of redrawing the background canvas, you can relocate the old one. All you have to do for that is to assign the drawn rectangle as an attribute of the line and then change its position. I would still have to keep a list of all the lines but I think it's a much nicer solution than the one I had already found. The new and working code looks like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<TopLayout>:
    Button:
        text: 'Remove middle line'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        on_press: root.remove_middle_line()
<Line>:
    size_hint: 1, .1
    Label:
        text: 'This is a line with a background-color'
""")
lines = []

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TopLayout()

class TopLayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global middle_line
        middle_line = Line()
        self.add_widget(Line())
        self.add_widget(middle_line)
        self.add_widget(Line())

    def remove_middle_line(self):
        self.remove_widget(middle_line)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.redraw, 0)

    def redraw(self, delta):
        for line in lines:
            line.rect.pos = line.pos


class Line(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)
        lines.append(self)

    def init_ui(self, delta=0):
        if self.pos == [0, 0]:
            Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)
        else:
            with self.canvas.before:
                Color(.4, .2, .2, .8)
                self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

TestApp().run()
```

Thanks anyway and please feel free to add to this question if you have anything on your mind.